# How to disable node mongodb-native driver connections logging in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, message

When I start the node server that connects to mongodb I always get these messages telling me the status of the connection. How Can I disable these messages?

```
Wed Apr 24 13:28:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55221 #304 (1 connection now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:28:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55222 #305 (2 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:28:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55223 #306 (3 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:28:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55224 #307 (4 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:28:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55225 #308 (5 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:35:42 [conn308] end connection 127.0.0.1:55225 (4 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:35:42 [conn307] end connection 127.0.0.1:55224 (4 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:35:42 [conn306] end connection 127.0.0.1:55223 (4 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:35:42 [conn305] end connection 127.0.0.1:55222 (4 connections now open)
Wed Apr 24 13:35:42 [conn304] end connection 127.0.0.1:55221 (4 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is not coming from node.js or the node-mongodb-native driver. It is coming from the mongo daemon.

When Starting mongo simply pass the --quiet option and this message will disapear.